# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate array of object not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I try to update array of object with mongoose methodes. When i try with vanila JS it worked but with mongoose not.

model:

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    arrayOfObjects: [
        { name: String, id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    ],
});
```

find and update by vanila js

```
const example = await Example.findById(req.body.propertyX);
const validIndex = example.arrayOfObjects.findIndex((v) => v.propertyY === req.body.Y);
if (validIndex === -1) {
    example.arrayOfObjects.push({ propertyY: req.body.Y, propertyZ: req.body.Z });
} else {
    example.arrayOfObjects[validIndex] = { propertyY: req.body.Y, propertyZ: req.body.Z };
    console.log('update');
}
await recipe.save();
```

but when I try use findByIdAndUpdate , $set methode dont work (even $push not working...push is pushing new object id without req.body fields)

mongoose findByIdAndUpdate

```
const example = await Example.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.x, {
    // arrayOfObjects: { $push: { propertyY: req.body.Y, propertyX: req.body.X} },
    $set: { 'arrayOfObjects.$.propertyY': req.body.Y, 'arrayOfObjects.$.propertyX': req.body.X },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your understand of the positional operator [$](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), from the docs:

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, and

This means it excepts to find a match in the array based on the query, in your case the query does not contain anything regarding the `voted` array, so you get the following error:

> [The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.]

---

So what can we do? actually doing the update you want is not so trivial, it only became possible in recent years with the introduction of [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) which allow you to use aggregation operators in your update body, now we can do what you want like so:

```
db.collection.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.postId,
[
  {
    $set: {
      voted: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$voted",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      voted: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$voted",
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this.voterId",
                  req.body.userId
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          [
            {
              $mergeObjects: [
                {
                  $ifNull: [
                    {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        {
                          $filter: {
                            input: "$voted",
                            cond: {
                              $eq: [
                                "$$this.voterId",
                                req.body.userId
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        0
                      ]
                    },
                    {}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  voteRank: req.body.rank,
                  voterId: req.body.userId
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4rRT43eNLFQ)

You can drop the `$mergeObjects` operator if you don't need it, I added it incase the object could have additional properties that you want to preserve throughout an update. but probably not the case.
It then simplifies the code a little:

```
db.collection.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.postId,
[
    {
        $set: {
            voted: {
                $ifNull: [
                    '$voted',
                    [],
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            voted: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$voted',
                            cond: {
                                $ne: [
                                    '$$this.voterId',
                                    req.body.userId,
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    [
                       {
                          voteRank: req.body.rank,
                          voterId: req.body.userId
                       }
                    ],
                ],
            },
        },
    },
]);
```

Comment: Your answer is 10 level above my experience with Mongo. can i ask what is the advantage doing in this way in comparison to the vanilla js as i mention in my first example ?

Comment: I would say for a single update it's not that impactful, mainly saving network overhead as it's 1 db call instead of 2 but definitely not crucial.

Comment: This approach can be more impactful in larger scale updates - assume you wanted go update 1000 documents at once, suddenly this will save 1999 db calls